# can't see the cart icon responsive mode

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

My cart icon in the navbar toggle is not showing up when I go into a smaller display.

I am using bootstrap 5 for the navbar, I can click on the bottom of the toggler and it brings me to the my cart page but I can't see the actual icon.
Anyone have an idea on how I can fix this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
      <a href="" class="navbar-brand ms-auto">Meat</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a href="/html/ailes/fruits&vegetables.html" class="nav-link lead">Fruits & Vegetables</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a href="/html/ailes/dairy&eggs.html" class="nav-link lead">Dairy & Eggs</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a href="/html/ailes/snacks.html" class="nav-link lead">Snack</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a href="/html/ailes/drinks.html" class="nav-link lead">Drinks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-4">
          <a href="/html/ailes/bakery.html" class="nav-link lead">Bakery</a>
        </li>
        <a href="/html/cart.html"> <i class="bi bi-basket2-fill h2 cart-color"></i></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I see it above in both mobile and desktop modes. Did you add the icon library link?

Comment: hi, yes I did.
So you can see it on your side ?
I just checked on 3 different browser, I can't see it:(

Comment: Please read & follow bootstrap docs for navbar here - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

your cart icon element is exist but on a tablet, the size would go out of range of the screen.
you can fix this issue by trying to use one of these methods :

1 - try to re-responsive the navbar (with bootstrap you can use COl styling)
for this method try to read grid doc from the bootstrap website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/

2 : you can give the  icon "position absolute".
but I won't suggest this method because it is not so professional.